# Creating a powershell array on the fly

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am creating a powershell script and need some help.
I need to create an array and attach it to a string.

I have 3 required parameters

```
$printername
$start
$end
```

So if user enters the following for the 3 parameters: hp, 1, 5
I need to attach the following to a string called $printers
    $printers = 
    hp1
    hp2
    hp3
    hp4
    hp5.

If they entered 1000 for the last parameter this would have to go through hp1000

How can I create this array.

Answer (score 3):

Seems simple enough.

```
function Make-PrinterString
{
   Param (
    [string]$Prefix,
    [int]$Start,
    [int]$End
    )

   [string]($start..$end | foreach {"$Prefix$_"})
}

Make-PrinterString HP 1 5

HP1 HP2 HP3 HP4 HP5
```